# Video js. Doesn't play on iOS 5.x (iPad 1), iOS 6.x (iPhone 4)

Tags: html, video, video.js

I'm embedding a video with video.js 4.0 which I converted to MP4 from mpeg with Handbrake (H.264) with videojs. I subsequently converted the mp4 to ogv and webm (online-convert.com).

The video is not playing on iOS 5.1 (iPad 1) or 6.1.2 (iPhone 4). It does work however on 6.x on the latest gen iPad, all mac and PC browsers (down to ie7). On iOS 5.1 (iPad 1), I just get an endless spinner. On iOS 6.1.2 (iPhone 4) I get the play symbol with a line through it.

Here's my embed code:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="1050" height="588" poster="/img/posterframe.jpg"
     data-setup="{}">
        <source src="/video/Design_Sketch_new.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="/video/Design_Sketch_new.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
        <source src="/video/Design_Sketch.webm" type='video/webm'>
    </video>
```

Anyone have any ideas? Do I need to encode the file differently? Supply an additional format? Embed the video any differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wondering, it was due to the video size. It had 1080p which the older devices don't like. I reduced it to 480 and it's all good. See here: http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/video-js-issues-on-ipad/